# Taking a string of letters and placing them into an array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, token

I have a string, "ABCDEFG" and I want to make an array that would look like this:

```
array[0] = "A"
array[1] = "B"
array[2] = "C"
etc.
```

Do I have tokenize the original string, or is there some type of built in way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want an array of strings, like you have shown?  Either way, you can just loop over each character in the original string - is that original string a `char*` or a `std::string` ?

Comment: I think I misunderstood. In what form do you have the string?

Comment: The original string is an std::string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make an array of strings, you can do it with a loop:

```
const char *str = "ABCDEFG";
string letters[7];
for (int i = 0 ; i != strlen(str) ; i++) {
    // The constructor below cuts out a single letter from the literal:
    letters[i] = string(&str[i], &str[i+1]);
}
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/olzeKv).

For `std::string` original string, use `substr` ([demo](http://ideone.com/8QKab5)):

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != str.size() ; i++) {
    letters[i] = str.substr(i, 1);
}
```

Comment: I think this is close, but my string isn't a char string, but an std string, this causes an overload error when used with what I have.